# Apache FOP applet error Unknown function: gatherContextInfo

Tags: java, apache, applet, apache-fop

I'm trying to use FOP to generate a pdf file in a signed applet, but, i got these errors:

```
Dez 10, 2013 2:09:45 PM org.apache.fop.fo.properties.PropertyCache <init>
Informações: Unable to access org.apache.fop.fo.properties.use-cache due to security restriction; defaulting to 'true'.

ERROR:  'Unknown function: gatherContextInfo'
```

I tried the same code in a desktop application, and everything works fine, the problem is just in the applet.

Comment: This applet apparently needs to be digitally signed by you, and trusted by the end user (when prompted).

Comment: *"It's already signed."*  Now would be a good time for more words, rather than less.  How is the applet deployed (JNLP/standard HTML)?  Is the app. trusted by the end user (they should be prompted)?

Comment: Its standard HTML, the applet and it's dependencies are signed with the same key. And yes, it's trusted by the end user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

I had to add the provided xalan.jar in fop-bin.zip to the classpath.

I guess it includes the unknown function while the built in implementation in JRE not.